# How to use DATEDIFF function correctly when datetime is stored as UTC in DB, but you want to find difference in days

Tags: java, sql-server, date, datetime, utc

*Use case:* 
I need to get a list of tasks that are ontarget or overdue from database.
A task is said to be on target if the task is finished within 3 days and overdue after 3 days from assigned date.

### *For example:*

If Assigned Date: 6th September then any task till 9th Sept end will be said on target but from 10th Sept it will be overdue.

The problem is we store the assigned date as datetime in UTC in database, 
Let's say the user is in CST so for him

- 6th Sept 00:00:00 CST  is 6th Sept 05:00:00 UTC
- 6th Sept 19:00:00 CST is 7th Sept 00:00:00 UTC
- 6th Sept 23:59:59 CST  is 7th Sept 04:59:59 UTC

Now, as you see for user which is in CST his entire date for 6th Sept can be represented by 2 dates in UTC(i.e 6th and 7th Sept)

So, when we do **DATEDIFF(day,assigned_date,currentdate)<=3**, lets say current date is 10th Sept,

- ***Issue 1:***

When assigned_date < (6th Sept 19:00:00 CST which is 7th Sept 00:00:00 UTC), it will do 6-10 -> 4 days which is correct
But when the assigned_date > (6th Sept 19:00:00 CST which is 7th Sept 00:00:00 UTC) and <(6th Sept 23:59:59 CST  is 7th Sept 04:59:59 UTC) it will be 7-10-> 3 days and hence won't be seen as overdue, which is wrong. (As for user today's date is still 6th September and hence it should be seen as overdue)

- ***Issue 2:***

Also, I might check this task on 10th Sept later after 10th Sept 19:00:00 CST which will take current date as 11th Sept instead of 10th Sept
which will again be a problem, which I can still manage as I am sending it from front end but assigned_date is stored in database as datetime.

- ***Issue 3:***

I thought of using the offset in java to convert DATEDIFF to DATEADD function, which will first convert assigned_date(which is datetime) to required timezone by providing the offset and then CAST it to date, but the problem is the offset might depend on what month it is as daylight saving time may change the offset for UTC.
Example:

```
package datetime;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class UTCOffset {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Calendar obj= Calendar.getInstance();
        obj.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
        obj.set(2018,11,12); 
        System.out.println(obj.getTimeZone().getOffset(obj.getTimeInMillis())/3600000); //In November-> DayLight -> Returns -6
        Date d = new Date(); Today 9th Sept
        System.out.println(obj.getTimeZone().getOffset(d.getTime())/3600000); // Today in September returns -5
    }

}
```

So, the offset is also different based on the date.

Can any one point out how can we solve these issues?

Comment: If you were able to redefine "overdue" to be "72 hours" rather than "3 days" then you can work out a precise UTC timestamp at which it becomes overdue, sidestepping the whole time zone issue  entirely. Are you able to do that?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, that would help. But our requirement is fixed they want it as per days and not time like 72 hr after that. So, trying to figure out how it can be done on database side.

Comment: You could still work out (in the calling code) the UTC timestamp that is the boundary between overdue and not overdue, then put that in a query. Although I suspect I could come up with corner cases around DST transitions that are ambiguous, if I tried hard enough...

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, that's what is the 3 issue I have mentioned in the question, is my problem

Comment: My point is that you don't need to do the datediff in the database. Work out "3 days before now, converted to UTC" in the calling code, then do a simple query based on that.

Comment: @JonSkeet But the problem is I don't have my date(assigned_date). It's in the database and I need to do 3 days from that date(assigned_date) and not the currentdate/now.

Comment: So what two dates are you trying to get the difference between? I thought that *one* of them would be "now".

Comment: To be clearer now I'm not on a mobile: in Java, you work out the instant that separates "overdue jobs" from "not overdue jobs", in terms of the assigned_date. For example, "now - 3 days, in time zone X". You then pass *that* value into the query, just checking whether assigned_date is more or less than that value. This will make things much simpler, but it does rely on: a) you comparing with "now" or some other locally-known value; b) the number of days being constant.